# Target an attribute in a collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to target 'status' under 'attributes. How would I do this? So far I have this:

```
$this->followers->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
```

[image: When above is DD()]

Comment: `$object->status`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `$followers` instance of `Collection` you can do it if item count is one

```
$followers = $this->followers->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);
echo $followers->first()->status;
```

or when item count more then one

```
foreach($followers as $follower) {
    echo $follower->status;
}
```